# Ember.js Rendering default content to a nested outlet

Tags: ember.js

How do I render default content into a nested outlet?

For example, if I have an index template such as this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <div>{{outlet}}</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="photo">
    Photo!
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="default">
    Default photo
</script>
```

And a nested routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('index', { path: '/'}, function() {
        this.resource('default');
        this.resource('photo', { path: ':id' });
    });
});
```

That works fine when I use to link-to helper to load the page into the outlet. However, I cannot work out how to render default content into the outlet when the page first loads.

If I do something like this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        this.render('default');
    },
});
```

It renders the default content into the main outlet. If I try to specify a named outlet instead:

```
this.render('default', { outlet: 'centre' });
```

I get the following error message:

> Error while processing route: index.index Assertion Failed: An outlet (centre) was specified but was not found. Error: Assertion Failed: An outlet (centre) was specified but was not found.

Even when using a named outlet:

```
{{outlet "centre"}}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Index is your route, so you are going to need to name your route `IndexIndexRoute` according to your naming schema

Comment: Agreed with @oshikryu for your scenario. It probably makes sense to change the routing to something more sane in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I used oshikryu's solution.

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <div>{{outlet}}</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="photo">
    Photo!
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="default">
    Default photo
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('index', { path: '/'}, function() {
        this.resource('photo', { path: ':id' });
    });
});

App.IndexIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('default');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the index resource, it's already created for you and will make things confusing.  Also, if you're needing to hook `renderTemplate` this early in the game, you're probably not following Ember's conventions.

I would also suggest removing the `default` resource, as Ember provides that by way of index.  The top template is application.hbs, which essentially just has an {{outlet}} in it.  So in summary:

- Delete the index template
- Change id="default" to id="index"
- Remove the index resource from your router map